# awk: passing variables from bash to use in an if statement

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to list the last users logged in before 2pm to a machine. I set two bash variables to use with the last command piped to awk.

```
month=$(date | awk '{printf"%s\n",$2}')
yesterday=$(date | awk '{printf"%s\n",$3-1}')
```

I then try to use these two variables, but it doesn't work when I do it like this.

```
last | awk -v month="$month"'{
    if($5==month && $6=="19" && $7 < "14:00"){
        printf "%s\n",$0
    }
}'

last | awk -v month="$month" -v yesteday="$yesterday" '{
    if($5==month && $6==yesterday && $7 < "14:00"){
        printf "%s\n",$0
    }
}'
```

Both of these attempts did not work. However, if I set the variables to a string like "Apr" it does work. Like so:

```
last | awk -v month="Apr" '{
    if($5==month && $6=="19" && $7 < "14:00"){
        printf "%s\n",$0
    }
}'
```

Here is output of it working with the above command.

[image: output for last|awk]

My question is, how can I get it to work with my bash variables? I looked at similar questions but those didn't help me. My bash variables work if I just set them then print them using awk, but it isn't working when I use them in my if statement.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you include some of the input data that contains the month at `$5`? Also, what operating system are you using? (I.e. which version of `date` -- GNU, BSD, something else?) Also, please consider copying and pasting formatted text into your question rather than images. If we want to replicate your results, we shouldn't have to re-type your code and input data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two issues with your code.

First, you should remove the trailing new line from here:

```
month=$(date | awk '{printf"%s\n",$2}')
yesterday=$(date | awk '{printf"%s\n",$3-1}')
```

It should be:

```
month=$(date | awk '{printf"%s",$2}')
yesterday=$(date | awk '{printf"%s",$3-1}')
```

Or just:

```
month=$(date | awk '{print $2}')
yesterday=$(date | awk '{print $3-1}')
```

Second, you have a typo here:

```
-v yesteday="$yesterday"
```

Should be:

```
-v yesterday="$yesterday"
```

Other than these, your code works for me (assuming you cut away three fields in your screenshot).

Comment: Thank you! I think it wasn't working because my variable included the trailing new line. It now works. I should've realized that. Thanks!

Comment: @Camilo - Warning...  You are now able to solve this problem badly but with success, rather than solving it badly with failure. Yes, you can strip the newline, but you wouldn't have to drop the newline if you were doing this better in the first place. Do consider switching Pax's `date +%b` suggestion, and consider what your script will do at the beginning of the month. [BSD date's `-v` option](http://man.freebsd.org/date) will help you with that. ("Yesterday" from the perspective of May 1st will not be May 0th.)

Comment: Thank you, I will improve it to cover these cases.

Comment: @Camilo, try debugging it yourself. Try some test scripts. For example, what is the output of `echo 1 | awk -v ystd=$(date --date="yesterday" +%d) '{ print ystd; if(ystd==21) print "OK"; }'`?

Comment: @ghoti, as a side note: `date +%b` returns `4月` on my machine. So even this is specific to your locale.

Comment: Actually, the trailing newline isn't a problem -- `$( )` strips any trailing newline(s), so it was never getting into the variable in the first place. Try `[ "$(date | awk '{print $2}')" = "$(date | awk '{printf"%s\n",$2}')" ] && echo "No difference"` and see what happens.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, thanks. On my machine the newline also didn't go into the variable, but I wasn't sure if it was the expected behavior on all systems and configurations.

Answer (score 1):

Just for debugging purposes, find out what your `month` is actually being set to. It's definitely not `Apr` for me:

```
pax$ date
Monday 23 April  10:58:57 AWST 2018
pax$ date | awk '{printf"%s\n",$2}'
23
```

Here, the month is held in the *third* field and, in any case, it appears to be the *long* form of the month rather than the short form. So you may think you can simply modify the command to suit your situation, such as with:

```
pax$ date | awk '{printf"%s\n",substr($3,1,3)}'
Apr
```

That, of course, will only work if your `date` output is similar to mine, probably not guaranteed. If you have a decent enough implementation of `date`, you can just use *its* formatting options:

```
pax$ date +%b
Apr
```

That's probably going to be much better rather than fiddling about with manipulating the entire date. What that boils down to in your case is simply setting `month` thus:

```
month=$(date +%b)
```

---

However, even fixing *that* isn't going to help you here because there's *no* way that the script you gave produced the output you specified (unless you've cut fields off the left). Your script calls for the moth and day to be in fields 6 and 7 respectively but the output clearly has it in fields 2 and 3.

Comment: $ date
Sun Apr 22 19:39:55 PDT 2018

Comment: @Camilo `date`'s default output format depends on your locale (and probably other things), so it's best to specify a format (like `%b`) rather than depending on the default.